# ZF2 - How to enable Twig's Debug / Dump function

Tags: debugging, zend-framework2, twig

Does anyone one know where to enable Twig's dump function in ZF2?

I've looked all over Google and I can't find anything that really relates to this issue. I would have though the ZFC-Twig module would have it right in their config but it doesn't appear to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html), you need to activate Twig_Extension_Debug extension to have this function available.

In ZfcTwig module just add this extension to config ([doc](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig#setting-up-twig-extensions)):

```
'zfctwig' => [
    'extensions' => [
        'Twig_Extension_Debug',
    ],
],
```

Comment: According to the ([docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html)) this is just half of it. I was just unsure where and what to put into the environmental variables.

You also need to add this to the 'environment_options'. If you don't you won't get any display data.

`'environment_options' => array('debug' => true),`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Zfc-Twig, you can enable debug feature by enabling it through *environment_options* like this:

```
<?php

// enable debug
return array(
    'zfctwig' => array(
        'environment_options' => array(
            'debug'         => true
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This only makes available __toString function in templates, see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options

Comment: This was the other half of what @lku posted. You need both to make get the debug to show up.